# Cannot convert from 'System.Web.Mvc.ModelStateDictionary' to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ModelStateDictionary'

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

When I try to build my WEB API project on MS VS 2015 I am getting an **error**as shown below.

> CS1503    Argument 3: cannot convert from
>   'System.Web.Mvc.ModelStateDictionary' to
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ModelStateDictionary'

.

Comment: I don't know why they down-voted you, but I had exactly same problem, and would never figure it out if I didn't see it on yours question. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

In your project you are using `System.Web.ModelBinding` so please change it to using `System.Web.Mvc`;

Comment: Hey man, thanks a lot, I would have never figure it out if it weren't for you.